# thread safety on public variables access

Tags: c++, boost, thread-safety, mutex, getter-setter

I have some private variables (say int a, int b, int c) inside my class. Due to some internal manipulations I need to set/get such variables in a thread safe way so I used some wrapping getters/setters and used a scoped mutex.

```
void setA(int a)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(opMutex);

    this->a = a;
}

void getA(int a)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(opMutex);

    return a;
}

void setB(int b)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(opMutex);

    this->b = b;
}

void setC(int c)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(opMutex);

    this->c = c;
}
```

My question is: is it possbile to avoid getter/setter methods (public variables) and keep thread safety on assign/read operations over such variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar library in Boost, [boost::atomic](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/doc/index.html) but it's not yet included in the standard AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

If you move your thread security synchronization code outside the getters setters, and bloat your code with boilerplate code locking mutexes everywhere, yes it's possible not to use getter and setters, but it would be **really counter-productive**.

Answer (score 3):

If C++11 is an option, consider using [`std::atomic_store` and `std::atomic_load`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_store) with `atomic_int`. However, you probably should still stay with getters/setters, so your decisions on how you manage your data (e.g., the choice between atomics and mutexes) won't affect the class users, even if that's only you :)

If C++11 is not an option, you can use one of the C++98 compatible implementations of atomic operations out there. I've used the [proposed boost atomic library](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/doc/index.html) for quite some time and there are other implementations roaming the Internets.

Comment: it's ok but I've got to work with the plain old C++98 standard

Comment: There is some work-in-progress towards Boost.Atomic http://git.chaoticmind.net/cgi-bin/cgit.cgi/boost.atomic/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::atomic<int> a, b, c;`

PS. Ugh, I didn't see the boost tag, so I thought you're talking C++11 ...

Comment: interesting, does the atomic type redefines the assign operator in a thread safe one?

Comment: @chill: nope, just vanilla C++98 standard + boost lib

Comment: @G_G A number of specializations are supplied by the standard library. You can use "value semantics" to access and set the atomic value so it is used much like a normal int. The standard library is actually free to not use a lock when it knows the variable is properly aligned that data type can be set/accessed atomically on the architecture. Take a look here for the atomic types the C++11 standard library provides you: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic